# Block certain employers from finding your profile

Tags: feature-request, jobs

As an already employed user of Stackoverflow Careers I want to block specific past and current employers from finding my profile so that I won't appear in their recruitment results and get me in trouble :)

Comment: Isn't that as simple as switching your profile to "not actively looking for work?"

Comment: I don't think so, since that would mean _no_ employers could browse your profile or see it in a search (correct me if I'm wrong....)

Comment: I don't think this is possible... I mean, is this feature also implemented on most of career sites?

Comment: @AndrewT. -  hired.com